# How to access every "Item" detail in this Mongo Collection using PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, database-cursor

```
<?php

$connection =new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([]);
$rows = $connection->executeQuery("test.orders", $query);

$cursor=$rows;

foreach ($cursor as $value) {
    if($value->FirstName=="Bumbum"){
    echo ("The order's ID is: $value->OrderID " . "and the e-mail is " . $value->OrderEmail ."<br>"  );
    }
}
?>
```

So far, this is the code for accessing some fields. I have to extract the data from **Item**, and eventually save it in objects, but mainly to access it. Below is a part of the collection:

```
  "_id": "5ec6b57e586d3bae94b1e756",
  "OrderID": "3",
  "FirstName": "Bumbum",
  "LastName": "Ai",
  "OrderEmail": "doesntmatter@yahoo.com",
  "OrderDate": "2018-03-15T10:44:50",
  "OrderItems": {
    "Item": {
      "ItemID": "15",
      "ItemStatus": "Item Shipped - Tracking Sent",
      "ItemStatusId": "17",
      "ItemPrice": "49.9700"
    }
  }
}
```

I kept on searching for days now but I can't figure it out, filtering doesn't work. Tried to go in that foreach : `if($value->OrderItems->Item->ItemStatus)` but it doesn't work farther than *Item*. I tried the *find() method*, didn't work, and many more, with lots of problems.
I find the documentation on PHP with Mongo quite difficult, since I encountered lots of tutorials with outdated information.

Comment: What does "Not working" mean? I cannot see where you try to access those props in your code.

Comment: I have deleted those, for example while filtering I was trying to display the code and had errors on Array to/from String conversion. I highlighted ```if($value->OrderItems->Item->ItemStatus)``` because i encountered this error: Trying to get property 'ItemStatus' of non-object

Comment: So there you have it. `OrderItems->Item` is not an object. So it is either `null` or an `array`.

Comment: And it is an array clearly, I mean, it is not ```null``` and on the other 3 orders, ```Item``` is an ```array``` . Still, I can not figure it out :/

Comment: You cannot access arrays with arrow syntax, you have to use indizes e.g. `->Item["ItemID"]`

Comment: I'm an idiot, thank you very much! Now I'm using only ```$value->Item["ItemStatus"]==""Item Shipped - Tracking Sent" ``` as an **IF** argument. It displays this error **Undefined property: stdClass::$Item ** . Do you have any idea what could cause this ?

Comment: We cannot repeat this for every property. The generally rule in PHP when you parse JSON like structures is that it can be parsed either as an object (stdClass) or an associative array. I dont now exactly how your "schema" looks but when you have optional fields in your objects/arrays you should use a combination of `isset`, `empty` and `property_exists` to check if those properties are actually defined before accessing them.

Comment: Well, it is empty. No matter what is the argument of ```Item[]``` (either **"ItemStatus" or "1"** ). In schema, i have more fields preceeded by an A, and the last one, `OrderItems` is preceeded by brackets, upon click revealing it contains the `Item`. Upon clicking Item it should show what it contains, at least that is what I am expecting but it doesn't. If you find it hard to understand because I'm a newb, we can talk through e-mails and send you some screenshots